# php mysqli stmt

Tags: php, mysqli

i'm new to the php mysql usage.  i'm selecting the results from database .. and i'm cycling/printing them out to the screen using  while($stmt->fetch()): .. what i'd like to do is to cycle through the results again after the first cycle without calling the database (frombuffered results set).

i'm using php5, mysqli, stms on xampp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use arrays.

When you cycle through the result for the first time you can put the values in the array and later in the 2nd cycle you can access the elements from the array.

Something like:

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM EMP";

$arr = array();
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

        $stmt->execute();                                  

        $stmt->bind_result($name);

        // 1st cycle.
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $arr[] = $name; // save in array.
        }   

        $stmt->close();

        // 2nd cycle.
        foreach($arr as $name) {
                // use $name again.
        }   
}
```

Comment: thnx man! i'll store this lines straight into my code library ;-)

Comment: what would be the best way to use more than just one field here in this exeample of yours?  let say we have $street, $name and $phone

Comment: You can use a multidimensional array. `$arr[] = array($name,$street,$phone);`

Comment: i got it ...  i have to set an array to an $arr[] instead of just $name

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
  $storedRows[] = $row;
  //do stuff
}
foreach($storedRows as $row){
  //do more stuff
}
```

Comment: goddamn, this stackoverflow works!!  damn! :-)   thank for the answers